# Adding TypeScript to React-Native Expo project

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

**I am trying to add TypeScript to a React-Native Expo project and get the following error if I rename any file `abc.js` to `abc.tsx`:**

I have been following the instructions at:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/05/07/using-typescript-with-react-native
- https://medium.com/@rintoj/react-native-with-typescript-40355a90a5d7

**How can I address this?**

---

rn-cli.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  getTransformModulePath() {
    return require.resolve('react-native-typescript-transformer');
  },
  getSourceExts() {
    return ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'];
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    //"strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create the rn-cli.config.js . You can add element to it inside app.json to let the packager know you use ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*With version 31 + typescript can be add much more easily https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/typescript/*

First install the dev dependencies `react-native-typescript-transformer`

You need to add in your `app.json` file this config. This will make expo know you use ts.

```
 "packagerOpts": {
      "sourceExts": [
        "ts",
        "tsx"
      ],
      "transformer": "node_modules/react-native-typescript-transformer/index.js"
    },
```

Stop expo and restart after doing these changes.

If you use vanilla react-native the `rn-cli.config.js` file is the response, but here in expo this is how I make it work.

Comment: If I have both js/jsx and ts/tsx files in the same project, do I need to add js and jsx to that array?

Comment: you want to keeps js and jsx file even if you use ts ? I don't think so, here that just let know the compiler than you need to match ts and tsx with the new transformer below.

Comment: Ok, so that addresses the error. But now I receive a new error `undefined is not an object(evaluating 'react_1.default.Component')` on the line `export class PostFeedScreen extends React.Component<Props, State> {`

Comment: Inside your tsconfig.json add this line `    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`

Comment: I already have that line, see my updated question above for the full file.

Comment: Can you try just for fun if `import * as React from 'react'` work ? That will help for know what is the error here.

Comment: This is the tsconfig.json I always use with expo here https://gist.github.com/EQuimper/8fa9ab89638d8cd12cdd02bcc182c4d7

Comment: Ok so can you add this `"module": "es2015"` to your tsconfig this will fix this and let you import default.

Comment: Adding `"module": "es2015"` to my tsconfig and changing it back to `import React from 'react';`  produces error `Unexpected end of script(` Also my phone now gets stuck at `Downloading JavaScript bundle 100%` whenever I make a change.

Comment: after adding this change did you stop expo and restart. Every change in tsconfig you need to restart expo

Comment: I added a blank line at the end of the file, then stopped and restarted. Looks like it works now.

Comment: Nice great job :)

Comment: Ok, what if I want to access `this.props.example` inside the component? I currently get `Property 'example' does not exist on type`. Is there a way to suppress these kind of errors? I know that `this.props.example as any` works, but what if I wanted to access say `this.props.person.address` ?

Comment: You need to type your props now example `interface Props { example: string }` `class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props>`

Answer (score 6):

TS/TSX files work [out of the box with expo v31](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#-breaking-changes-2) but you'll probably want to include

**Package TypeScript types**

`yarn add @types/expo @types/react @types/react-native -D`

**Custom tsconfig.json**

Create `tsconfig.json` in the root directory next to `package.json`. It enforces strict mode and includes `App.tsx` (to replace `App.js`) and "custom_types" directory to add types for npm packages that don't include them.

```
// Defaults from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/08/27/typescript-and-babel-7/
// Added "jsx": "react-native".
// Added ["App.tsx", "custom_types"] to "include".
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // Target latest version of ECMAScript.
    "target": "esnext",
    // Search under node_modules for non-relative imports.
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // Output react-native code.
    "jsx": "react-native",
    // Don't emit; allow Babel to transform files.
    "noEmit": true,
    // Enable strictest settings like strictNullChecks & noImplicitAny.
    "strict": true,
    // Disallow features that require cross-file information for emit.
    "isolatedModules": true,
    // Import non-ES modules as default imports.
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "App.tsx", "custom_types"]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Expo 31 has built-in support for TypeScript: just name your component files with `.tsx` instead of `.js`.

The only exception is `App.js` – this file *must* be a `.js` file. However, you can still `import` other `.tsx` files from `App.js` with no extra steps.